# how to avoid importing the same Framework on every swift file

Tags: swift, import, frameworks

Is there a way to always import a few libraries on every file? 
without putting them into a framework

for example, instead of having to do

--MySwiftFile.swift--

```
import UIKit 
import Foundation
import ...
```

I could do something like:

--SharedImports.swift--

```
import UIKit 
import Foundation
import ...
```

--MySwiftFile.swift--

```
import SharedImports.swift
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is "No, and that's on purpose".  Each file needs to know the context of the code that is contained within that file.  It gets that context from the set of imports.

Now in the particular case of UIKit and Foundation, it should be the case that `UIKit` imports `Foundation` so I don't think you have to explicitly call out both in every file.  In the examples above you should be able to get by with just

```
import UIKit
```

There are times, when defining your application's model for example, where you may want a file to bring in `Foundation` and not `UIKit`.

Comment: i put the two of them just as an example but you're right. what if i had a local framework in my project and in the framework these libraries were imported I still need to import them explicitly, no ?

Comment: Yes.  Each file is compiled as a separate unit and each unit needs a complete context to know what's available to the code in that unit.

Comment: Somehow there is PrefixHeader.pch. You can do workaround: Create Objective-C file. Add all those libraries you want to have imported everywhere to PrefixHeader.pch and then import this Objective-C file via BridgingHeader... for sure doable and answer "definite NO" is wrong.